# Python textwrap ignoring length of some parts of string

Tags: python

I'm using textwarp to warp a big line to smaller lines with a specific length

```py
lines = wrap(line, 33)
```

its work as I excepted, but there is only one problem, my big string have some code in it that my program use to style the string

```css
test string with no color - This part is [#?color_red]red[#]. and this part is [#?color_blue]Blue[#] and...
```

but when Im using textwarp its also counts the codes as part of string and this make the length of string wrong in some case (because as you know these codes wont show up in my program, they just used for styling)
so my question is how can I make textwarp  Ignore these codes?

Comment: replace all such codes with strings like "#c1","#c2". Then wrap the text. Replace such #c strings with '\n'+actual code using dictionaries or file handling.

Comment: @HarshPrakashAgarwal in this way I still lose some char count, because textwarp read these characters and count them as well

Comment: I see you are right

Comment: I think then a special character wil have to be chosen that is not a part of text and placed before and after code.

Comment: @HarshPrakashAgarwal yes, the problem is I don't know anyway to do it in textWarp, if its was possible to set some kind of rule for it, then we could just make it stop count when read '[' character until its read ']' again